# How to remove button background resource

Tags: android, background

I set an image as background resource for a button, at button click I want to remove image and restore default button style.

I try with setBackgroundResource(0), but the button disappear.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerTest);
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic01);
}

private OnClickListener onClickListenerTest = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(final View v) {     
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for it to have the default android button style or have you done something custom for the background in activity_settings.xml and you want to return to that?

Comment: In my app the user can configure the buttons aspect, he can add an icon as background, but he must also have the possibility to remove the icon. Sam_D solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default));
```

Comment: This method is deprecated now; what's the 2015 way to do it?

Comment: this_button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default); for 2015

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

that reset also the associated resource id.

Answer (score -1):

For newer versions of Android, use

```
button.setBackground(null);
```